# How to do value_counts on each row and make some columns whose values are the counts of each value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get a dataframe as follows:

```
df
     c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12
r1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
r2   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0      
r3   1   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0      


func(df)
     0   1   2
r1   8   4   0
r2   3   5   4
r3   9   2   1
```

And I want to do `value_counts` on each row and get 3 columns which are corresponding to the count of each value.
What I thought is to do `melt()` in each row, get values counts and fill it in corresponding place. BUT I think it is not a smart and convenient enough way.
So if not mind could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not using apply please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using simple [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `0`

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

```
     0   1   2
r1   8   4   0
r2   3   5   4
r3   9   2   1
```

Comment: Please try not using apply , for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: @WeNYoBen ok I'll try not to use apply in future.Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
    0  1  2
r1  8  4  0
r2  3  5  4
r3  9  2  1
```

And with `crosstab` should be fast:-)

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index')
pd.crosstab(s['index'],s.value)
value  0  1  2
index         
r1     8  4  0
r2     3  5  4
r3     9  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Straightforwardly (with `Dataframe.apply` + `pandas.Series.value_counts`):

```
In [232]: df.apply(lambda s: s.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0)                                                  
Out[232]: 
      0    1    2
r1  8.0  4.0  0.0
r2  3.0  5.0  4.0
r3  9.0  2.0  1.0
```